# Regex for format ( HHh MMs SSs ) with optional hours

Tags: python, regex

I am struggling to get a regex working for the below format. Pointers appeciated

```
( 43m 12s )
( 13m 11s )
( 11h 43m 12s )
( 1h 43m 12s )
```

Edit:

The above examples are part of longer strings.

Edit2:

This is what I have now:

```
 \s\(\s\d{1,2}[a-z]\s.*\)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to capture hours minutes and seconds, this will work: `\(\s?(?:\d{1,2}\w )+\s?\)` you can see it working here: https://regex101.com/r/yC8iH6/1

**[EDIT]**: Add capturing if needed:

If you need to capture you can do this:
`\(\s?(?:(\d{1,2})\w\s?)?(?:(\d{1,2})\w\s?)(?:(\d{1,2})\w\s?)\s?\)`. Notice that the first grouping is optional.

You can see this working version here: https://regex101.com/r/yC8iH6/2.

Also mote that first non capturing regex can be written like this for more accuracy `\(\s?(?:\d{1,2}\w ){2,3}\s?\)`.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to approach it with regular expressions.

Here is an another option - use a [`dateutil`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) datetime parser:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> l = ["43m 12s", "13m 11s", "11h 43m 12s", "1h 43m 12s"]
>>> for item in l:
...     dt = parse(item)
...     print(item, dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second)
... 
('43m 12s', 0, 43, 12)
('13m 11s', 0, 13, 11)
('11h 43m 12s', 11, 43, 12)
('1h 43m 12s', 1, 43, 12)
```

Or, you can use [`time.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) trying out `%Hh %Mm %Ss` and, if it fails, trying `%Mm %Ss` format.